# Better way to insert large number of rows in sql server using java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert some hundreds of thousands of records in SQL Server 2008 using java code. What would be the best approach to insert them in least amount of time? 
I am reading xls file and insert each row in database. My xls file contains around 65000 rows. It tales a lot time to insert into databse. I was used batch process but it will take also too much time.

Please suggest me the best optimised way to insert the data.
My Java code.

```
public String insertDataMigration(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> temp,String iConstantQuery, Connection conn) {
        int rowCount=0;
        String error = null;
        try {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(iConstantQuery);
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
                rowCount++;
                pstmt.setString(1, temp.get(i).get(0).toString());
                pstmt.setString(2, temp.get(i).get(1).toString());
                pstmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(temp.get(i).get(2).toString()));
                pstmt.setDouble(4, Double.parseDouble(temp.get(i).get(3).toString()));
                pstmt.setDouble(5, Double.parseDouble(temp.get(i).get(4).toString()));
                pstmt.setDouble(6, Double.parseDouble(temp.get(i).get(5).toString()));
                pstmt.setDouble(7, Double.parseDouble(temp.get(i).get(6).toString()));
                pstmt.setString(8, temp.get(i).get(7).toString());
                pstmt.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(temp.get(i).get(8).toString()));
                pstmt.setDouble(10, Double.parseDouble(temp.get(i).get(9).toString()));
                pstmt.setString(11, temp.get(i).get(10).toString());
                pstmt.setString(12, temp.get(i).get(11).toString());
                pstmt.setString(13, temp.get(i).get(12).toString());
                pstmt.setString(14, temp.get(i).get(13).toString());
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
//              pstmt.addBatch();
            }
//          pstmt.executeBatch();
            error="NO ERROR";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error=rowCount+"_"+e;
                pstmt.close();
                Constants.exceptionLogger.error("PayoutsDAO-insertData in try--" + e);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                Constants.exceptionLogger.error("PayoutsDAO-insertData in catch--" + e1);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                Constants.exceptionLogger.error("PayoutsDAO-insertData in finally--"+ e2);
            }
        }
        return error;
    }
```

My Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDataMigration_Bank](
    [REFERENCENO] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [Chq_No] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Debit] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Credit] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Balance] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Calculated_Balance] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Pay_Request_No] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Pay_Request_Amt] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
    [JE_No] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [Reconciliation_Flag] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Temp] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UPLOADDATE] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblDataMigration_Ledger] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [REFERENCENO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: This kind of questions is better located at [http://codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Jens Code Review might make the code look prettier, but there probably isn't much performance gain possible by tweaking a prepared statement executed in a loop. To improve performance, you might be better off asking [dba.se]. Perhaps a [`BULK INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) could help.  See the [MS TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for tips, such as temporarily disabling logging and indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends but you will need to use batch and call execute batch after something like 50-100 rows. This should be the most effective way.. you can try running with diffrent number because this also depends on your db instance.

something lime that:

```
 ...
 pstmt.setString(12, temp.get(i).get(11).toString());
 pstmt.setString(13, temp.get(i).get(12).toString());
 pstmt.setString(14, temp.get(i).get(13).toString());
 pstmt.addBatch();
 if ((i + 1) % 100 == 0) {
      pstmt.executeBatch(); // Execute every 100 items.
 }
```

EDIT:

In addition if this won't be good enough i would suggest to try this:

```
if ((i + 1) % 100 == 0) {
     pstmt.executeBatch(); // Execute every 100 items.
     psmt.clearParameters();
     psmt.clearBatch();
}
```

There is also tuning in the DB level, you can try to read this, it might help but this need better understanding of sql server

https://blogs.datadirect.com/2012/05/how-to-bulk-insert-jdbc-batches-into-microsoft-sql-server-oracle-sybase.html

Comment: This is running fine but it will also takes too muxh time to insert a data.Is their any another way to insert/update a rows in db?

Comment: Batch insert is the only way to insert large amount of data, how much insert do you need? You can try to increase batch size to 1000, Maybe this will be better for your needs.. But basically this is the only way.
You can call this method in different Thread if you don't need to wait for insert to finish. Look on the update from my response

Comment: NP.How much time it takes? 65000 rows?